# Display live instead of time in video player

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to display live text and live mark instead of duration time in html video player.
I have tried in many ways but I couldn't find the solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFg7g.png)

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: have a look at plyr.io ... allows you to play a live stream and hide the duration/time even if there is #EXT-X-ENDLIST in the live source